# SQL Server intellisense for columns not working for some tables in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, intellisense

I am having some troubles with intellisense in SQL Server 2008 R2.

Intellisense for all tables works fine, but the column intellisense only seems to work for some tables.

For example, this query pulls up a list of all the functions and navigates to the items starting with "sta":

```
select *
from tbl_cash_stats
where sta
```

This query doesn't pull up anything after the where clause regardless of if I type any characters or not

```
select *
from tbl_assignment
where
```

Furthermore, if I join a table that is working properly with one that is not, no column-level intellisense works:

```
select *
from tbl_cash_stats
join tbl_assignment
    on
```

I have refreshed local cache several times with no success. There appears to be no specific reason why certain tables work perfectly and others do not, and only about 15% of the tables are affected.

Does anyone have an idea of how to fix this? It has become extremely annoying because it is affecting some of the tables I use most often.

**EDIT: After looking into the tables that were affected more closely, it appears that it is only tables with an identity column that do not work with intellisense, but I still cannot figure out why.**

Comment: does adding `dbo.` help?

Comment: How about using the version of Management Studio that ships with SQL Server 2012? IntelliSense is much better, you can still manage old versions, and there are a lot of other improvements as well. Also the issue may be network-related. Have you done any comparisons between a table that works and doesn't, e.g. how many columns on each table?

Comment: @KM. No, unfortunately it does not.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Aha! It apparently doesn't work on tables with identity columns. I wonder why / how this can be fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of sheer luck I stumbled on the answer to this question.

On Friday, I installed Visual Studio 2010 SP1. After the install, I noticed that intellisense for SQL server stopped working completely. Apparently, this is a known issue and can be fixed by installing [Cumulative Update 9](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2567713)

Much to my suprise, this update also resolved the issue of intellisense not working on tables that had identity columns.

I hope this saves others from having to deal with this rather obscure issue in the future.